# How to run two instances of apache on same system (Ubuntu)

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

How can I run two instances of apache on the same system and start and stop them independently of each other. Any help or leads are appreciated.

Answer (score 13):

I think this might be what you are looking for
http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RunningMultipleApacheInstances

For reference of the content in the above link

**1) Install Apache on your server**

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-perl2
sudo apt-get install other-lib-mods-needed
```

**2) Configure separate apache configurations for each instance you want to run**

For Ubuntu, this should be in /etc/apache2
Essentially for each instance you need to listen on a different port.

```
# httpd-proxy.conf
Listen 80
ErrorLog /var/log/httpd-proxy-error.log
LoadModule proxy_module                 libexec/apache22/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module            libexec/apache22/mod_proxy_http.so

# httpd-perl.conf
Listen 81
ErrorLog /var/log/httpd-perl-error.log
LoadModule perl_module                  libexec/apache22/mod_perl.so

# httpd-python.conf
Listen 82
ErrorLog /var/log/httpd-python-error.log
LoadModule python_module                libexec/apache22/mod_python.so

# httpd-php.conf
Listen 83
ErrorLog /var/log/httpd-php-error.log
LoadModule php5_module                        libexec/apache22/libphp5.so
```

In this example, there would be 4 different instances running, each processing a different module type, i.e. one for perl, one for python, etc.

Now, you also need to configure the virtual hosts in the proxy instance, so that whenever a request comes for the subversion DAV server, it is passed onto your 'python-dav' apache, whereas requests for your wordpress blog are passed to your 'php' apache instance. Let's edit 'httpd-proxy.conf' again:

```
# httpd-proxy.conf
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot /www/wordpress
 ServerName blog.company.com
 ProxyPass / http://localhost:83/
 ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:83/
 [... additional directives here ... ]
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot /www/svn
 ServerName svn.company.com
 ProxyPass / http://localhost:82/
 ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:82/
 [... additional directives here ... ]
</VirtualHost>
# you get the idea ...
```

**2b) test everything**
So we're finished with the configuration, and now we need to launch all the apache instances, and test that everything is working as expected. Of course you can do this using 'apachectl', e.g.

```
 /usr/local/sbin/apachectl -f /usr/local/etc/apache22/proxy-httpd.conf configtest
 /usr/local/sbin/apachectl -f /usr/local/etc/apache22/proxy-httpd.conf start
 /usr/local/sbin/apachectl -f /usr/local/etc/apache22/perl-httpd.conf configtest
 /usr/local/sbin/apachectl -f /usr/local/etc/apache22/perl-httpd.conf start
 # and so on ...
```

**3) Configure the init scripts to start apache with the appropriate config file**

The linked resource has more detail on editing rc.conf file for this but touches specifically with dealing with Ubuntu so I both of these sections I will highlight below.

> The '/etc/rc.conf' in FreeBSD is the master file containing the system configuration >information. This file is read after booting the kernel, and serves to launch services, >daemons, set up network interfaces, etc. For our recipe we will be enabling the apache >server, listing the available instances (profiles), their configuration files, and >telling FreeBSD which of these need to be run (enabled) after booting the system.

```
# /etc/rc.conf
apache22_enable="YES"
apache22_profiles="proxy perl python php"

# the apache proxy instance
apache22_proxy_configfile="/usr/local/etc/apache22/httpd-proxy.conf"
apache22_proxy_enable="YES"

# the apache perl instance
apache22_perl_configfile="/usr/local/etc/apache22/httpd-perl.conf"
apache22_perl_enable="YES"

# the apache python instance
apache22_python_configfile="/usr/local/etc/apache22/httpd-python.conf"
apache22_python_enable="YES"

# the apache php instance
apache22_php_configfile="/usr/local/etc/apache22/httpd-php.conf"
apache22_php_enable="YES"
```

> When these profiles are configured in /etc/rc.conf, and enabled, they will be started >after successfully booting the system. If you want to declare a profile but you only want >to start the corresponding apache instance manually, you can just edit '/etc/rc.conf' and >say, e.g. :

```
 # the apache php instance
 apache22_php_configfile="/usr/local/etc/apache22/httpd-php.conf"
 apache22_php_enable="NO"
```

> Later, you can start/stop any apache instance manually using just the profile name >(proxy, perl, python, php), like this:

```
 /usr/local/etc/rc.d/apache22 start php
 /usr/local/etc/rc.d/apache22 stop perl
 ...
```

**3b) for Ubuntu**

> I'm not sure this will be similar (and painless) as in the case of FreeBSD (see section on rc.conf above). The apache rc scripts installed with the apache port in FreeBSD have been aware of the possibility of different profiles for years now.
>
> Recently, the Ubuntu/Debian init scripts (e.g. /etc/init.d/apache2) have been updated to support multiple instances of apache (e.g. multiple configurations, named /etc/apache2-$SUFFIX). Depending on the release of Ubuntu/Debian you're using you may be lucky ... or not.
>
> The feature appeared in Debian in version 2.2.14-6 in Feb 2010: http://lists.alioth.debian.org/pipermail/pkg-apache-commits/2010-February/000295.html
>
> In Ubuntu, the apache2 packages in Maverick (10.10) contain these patches: http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2_2.2.16-1ubuntu3.1/changelog
>
> However the Lucid (10.04, Long Term Support Release) apache2 apparently do not: http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2_2.2.14-5ubuntu8.4/changelog
>
> Documentation can be found in /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.multiple-instances

Comment: What a big fat mess. No offending to you, I just want to say that it's a pain in the S to do such stuff with linux.

Comment: Not sure I see the second mentioned installation process as any easier...so in reference to the original reply...

Why do we need the proxy? Is each individual configuration not sufficient to simply bind to distinct ports?

Comment: Our site does this and has separate /etc folders or each, they are totally independent. I need to know how to repair them so that both start as a service. I think it dates from certbot needing to pre-stop and post-start Apache2-80.

Answer (score 8):

Thanks for your detailed answer but later I found this link http://someofmylearnings.wordpress.com/2011/07/02/multiple-apache2-instances-on-ubuntu/ The procedure shown in this very simple.

When we install Apache, there is a `/usr/share/doc/apache2.2-common/README.multiple-instances` file which you gives an idea of what exactly needs to be done to create an Apache instance.

Inside the same directory there is an `examples` directory which contains a script named `setup-instance` that we can use to create an Apache instance. So, to create another Apache instance all that needs to be done is:

```
sh /usr/share/doc/apache2.2-common/examples/setup-instance web-server1
```

where `web-server1` is a suffix. That is, it appends “apache2-” by default to your instance name.

That will create a new directory `/etc/apache-web-server1` which contains all config files. It would also create `/etc/init.d/apache-web-server1` which you can use to start the new Apache instance.

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.04 LTS the doc directory is /usr/share/doc/apache2/

Comment: Actually I think this is a better solution because it allows separate start/stop via system service approach, and the instances are highly independent.

Comment: @bfrguci exactly why it is done.  50 - 80 virtual servers on 443 do not come down for Certbot.... Which only wants 80 nobbled.